# Stop touchpad from treating dust or fingerprints as finger

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

Seems like my touchpad is a bit oversensitive, every piece of dust or barely visible old fingerprint stains sometimes get treated as additional finger, which means it becomes unusable until I disabled, scrubbed and enabled it again. Lately this happens multiple times a day and is very annoying.

Can I reduce the touchpad sensitivity so that it is less prone to detect "ghost fingers"?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity Desktop, here's my touchpad info:

```
$ xinput list-props 12
Device 'SYN1B7F:00 06CB:7406 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (169):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (171): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (302): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (303):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (304):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (305):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (326):  49, 1187, 48, 850
    Synaptics Finger (327): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (328):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (329):   67
    Synaptics Tap Durations (330):  180, 100, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (331):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (332):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (333):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (334):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (335): 30, 30
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (336): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (337):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (338): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.130976, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (339):    2
    Synaptics Locked Drags (340):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (341):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (342): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2
    Synaptics Click Action (343):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (344): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (345):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (346): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (347):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (348): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (349):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (350): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (351):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (352): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (353):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (354):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (355):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (356):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (357): 12, 12
    Synaptics Area (358):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (359):  618, 0, 736, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (360): 7, 7
    Device Product ID (289):    1739, 29702
    Device Node (290):  "/dev/input/event13"
```

Comment: On MATE the mouse & touchpad settings include a sensitivity slider... it would drive me crazy not to be able to adjust it!

Comment: Unity has only pointer speed and doubleclick speed... :(

Answer (score 0):

you can lower the touchpad sensitivity by lowering the MaxTapTime parameter with synclient, by running syclient MaxTapTime=value.

If you set the value to 0 it disables the "tap to click" feature